# how to create MOCK_METHOD of auto return fuction?

Tags: c++17, googletest

for example, there is some class

```
class foo
{
public:
auto a() -> bool { return true; }
};
```

so I created mock class like this:

```
class bar : public foo
{
public:
MOCK_METHOD(bool, a, (), ());
};
```

but it's not working.
so I changed mock class

```
class bar : public foo
{
public:
MOCK_METHOD(auto, a, (), ());
};
```

and then, compile fail.
How can I do?
I can't change original class structure(class foo).

Comment: _"but it's not working"_ - Please include the exact error message you get or describe exactly _how_ it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock non-virtual methods anyway. If you can't modify `foo`, then the only option I see is to use template-based dependency injection. "*it's not working*" is because you probably try to inject `bar` where `foo` is expected and the call to `a` is calling base-class `foo::a` method, because there's no dynamic-dispatch happening (no virtual function) so `bar::a` is not in fact called. See:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class foo {
public:
    auto a() -> bool
    {
        return true;
    }
};

class bar : public foo {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, a, ());
};

TEST(BarTest, call_a) {
    bar b{};

    EXPECT_CALL(b, a).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

    ASSERT_TRUE(b.a());
}

bool ref_to_f(foo& f) {
    return f.a();
}

TEST(BarTest, call_a_by_ref_to_f) {
    bar b{};

    EXPECT_CALL(b, a).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

    ASSERT_TRUE(ref_to_f(b));
}

template<class F>
bool ref_to_f(F& f) {
    return f.a();
}

TEST(BarTest, call_a_by_ref_to_f_template_injection) {
    bar b{};

    EXPECT_CALL(b, a).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

    // note: use `ref_to_f<bar>` in tests, use `ref_to_f<foo>` in the production code
    ASSERT_TRUE(ref_to_f<bar>(b));
}
```

Gives:

```
[==========] Running 3 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from BarTest
[ RUN      ] BarTest.call_a
[       OK ] BarTest.call_a (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] BarTest.call_a_by_ref_to_f
/app/example.cpp:31: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(b, a)...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] BarTest.call_a_by_ref_to_f (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] BarTest.call_a_by_ref_to_f_template_injection
[       OK ] BarTest.call_a_by_ref_to_f_template_injection (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from BarTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 3 tests from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] BarTest.call_a_by_ref_to_f
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/E3nEfTjEK